# Create filtered connection in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a connection between two Excel files, however when I create multiple a pivot tables off this connected data, my file size dramatically increases.

I understand why this is happening (a pivot cache is created that from the entire source table and the source table contains hundred of thousands of rows). Saying that, I don't though need all of the data from the connected file.

What I would like to do is create a filtered connection based on column names and row values. ie

> SELECTcolA, colC, colF
>
> FROM myConnected Table
>
> WHERE colC is "myValue"

Does anyone know this is possible when connecting **two Excel files**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using the Power Query Add-In.  This can transform data from multiple sources (including filtering) and load it directly into the Excel Data Model (Power Pivot).

This is the best method for high volumes of data as the detail of the data does not need to be presented in an Excel table - the data is compressed and stored inside the Excel file, and made available for your Pivot Tables.